# Find the tallest element with a class: jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need a jQuery function that searches a list of elements, with the same class, and returns the height of the tallest element.

Any help would be great.

Comment: which element you talking about
Any specific

Comment: Apparently, including a link to whathaveyoutried dot com is blocked

Comment: Just this:
var maxHeight = maxHeight > $('.popup_bg').height() ? maxHeight : $('.popup_bg').height();

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$('.myclass').each(function(){
   maxHeight = $(this).height() > maxHeight ? $(this).height() : maxHeight;
});
alert(maxHeight);
```

Or:

```
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $('.myclass').map(function () {
    return this.clientHeight; // or $(this).height()
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $('.whatever').each(function () {
        maxHeight = Math.max($(this).height(), maxHeight);
    });
```