# Make previous smaller child div or last smaller child div match div with biggest height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 elements that are shown in a responsive layout. The responsiveness is working fine. The four elems have the same class and that's what the function is using as a reference.

These 4 elems are split up in 2 divs (parent1 and parent2).
 
**Parent1** contains 2 child divs(child1 and child3) and **parent2** contains 2 divs(child2 and child4)
- Child1 and child2 are the ones that need to be equally big.
- child3 and child4 are the ones that need to be equally big.

Example1: If child1 is bigger than 2, child1 should grow in equal size with child 2. Child3 and child4 should not grow.

Example 2: If child2 is bigger than child1, child1 should grow in equal size with child2. 
If child4 is bigger than child3, child3 should grow in equal size with child4.

I had written a function in **Jquery** which did work for a part. My problem is that it's somehow missing the first element in the loop and telling it to grow when the first one is smaller and the second one is bigger. The third and fourth elements are responding correctly. I'm getting kinda stuck in it because I just can't figure out why the first element is being passed over. Some fresh insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
var alignHeight = function () {
var cols = $(".presel-cell-path"); //.length;
var colslength = $(".presel-cell-path").length;
var previousHeight;
var elem;
var currentElem;

for (i = 0; i < colslength ; i++) {
    cols.eq(i).css({ "height": "auto" });
    if (previousHeight === 0 || previousHeight === undefined || previousHeight < cols.eq(i).height()) {
        elem = cols.eq(i);
        currentElem = i;
       // console.log(currentElem);
        previousHeight = cols.eq(i).height();
        //console.log(previousHeight);
    }
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        cols.eq(currentElem + 2).height(previousHeight);
        console.log("first:",currentElem);
    }

    else {
        cols.eq(currentElem - 2).height(previousHeight);
        console.log("second:", currentElem);
    }
}
```

}

**UPDATE**

For the Jquery code please review the fiddle.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cqfq56pe/4/)

Comment: Ps. It's called like this;

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    alignHeight();
});

Comment: Isn't it a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300085/find-the-tallest-element-with-a-class-jquery/17300172#17300172 ?

Comment: I see now that i'm not clear enough with my explanation. I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: A jsFiddle would be great imho

Comment: you could have saved yourself a lot of time by searching for existing answers instead of writing a "book" here

Comment: Tried that. Based on my findings I decided to write a book :)

Comment: Fiddle has been added :)

Comment: What is the mechanism of which one of the divs become irregular in size? Is this something that should run when the document is ready, or every time the site rescales?

Comment: I took out the resize. It was useless in the example anyway and it didn't add any extra info for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. Try this:

```
var alignHeight = function () {
    var parentDiv = $('.parentdiv');
    var childDivs = $('.childdiv');
    childDivs.height('auto');
    parentDiv.each(function(item){
        var currentChild = $(this).find('.childdiv');
        var firstChild = currentChild[0];
        var secondChild = currentChild[1];
        if($(firstChild).height() > $(secondChild).height()) {
            $(secondChild).height($(firstChild).height());
        } else if ($(firstChild).height() < $(secondChild).height()) {
            $(firstChild).height($(secondChild).height());
        }
    })
}

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    alignHeight();
});
```

Basically for each parent I check both children and see which one is bigger, and apply the same height to the other. I think that's what you desire.

If you want you can change the function for multiple children, inside the `parentDiv.each()` you check what is the biggest child and apply that height to all of them.

Comment: Thank you, This works because I know the amount of child divs. Your answer made me think of a version in which the amount of child divs is unknown. 

Many thanks!